# How to print from KVM guest (Windows 10) on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: ubuntu, windows, kvm, printing

I have setup KVM on Ubuntu 17.10 (host) and have Windows 10 running as guest OS on it. Attached to the computer is a USB printer. I would like to be able to print from the guest OS. Printer works fine when printing from host, but I cannot print from guest OS.

So far, the guest OS has been able to successfully connect to the outside world and can even access other computers on the Windows network. I have looked around SE but only found answers to VirtualBox or Linux guest.

Answer (score 0):

difficult and problematic issue. Try it
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2322683
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2329955
it's easier to put windows 10 in virtualbox. even an OKI printer works there